# Consuming SOAP response in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap

I'm having problems getting data out of the soap response. The request works fine, but I just can't get data out.
Here is the soap response (from soapui):

```
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <SOAP:Header/>
       <SOAP:Body>
      <createOrderResponse>
         <SAP_ORDER_NR/>
         <ORDER_STATUS>E</ORDER_STATUS>
         <TOTAL_GOODS_VALUE>0</TOTAL_GOODS_VALUE>
         <TOTAL_FREIGHT_VALUE>0</TOTAL_FREIGHT_VALUE>
         <TOTAL_VAT_VALUE>0</TOTAL_VAT_VALUE>
         <CASH_DISCOUNT>0</CASH_DISCOUNT>
         <ERROR_DESCR>multiple issues found</ERROR_DESCR>
         <MIN_ORDER_VALUE/>
         <ORDER_SCHEDULES_OUT/>
         <RETURN>
            <item>
               <TYPE>E</TYPE>
               <ID>VP</ID>
               <NUMBER>200</NUMBER>
               <MESSAGE></MESSAGE>
               <MESSAGE_V1></MESSAGE_V1>
            </item>
            <item>
               <TYPE>E</TYPE>
               <ID>V4</ID>
               <NUMBER></NUMBER>
               <MESSAGE></MESSAGE>
               <MESSAGE_V1/>
            </item>
         </RETURN>
      </createOrderResponse>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I need for example the SAP_ORDER_NR value.
alreay tried:

```
Convert.ToString(Response_1Run.SAP_ORDER_NR)
Response_1Run.SAP_ORDER_NR.tostring()
```

they all give "System.Object" as string.

update: screenshots
[image]

[image]

Comment: The <SAP_ORDER_NR> element is empty. What do you expect it to return in this scenario?

Comment: Why are you working with XML? Why not just use a Service Reference?

Comment: note: it's defined as object.

Comment: @pmartin: an empty string, but for nodes with data, i have the same results

Comment: john, can you explain, give sample?

Comment: info: the received wsdl file is imported to the project as webreference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using (do you even have access to) Response_1Run.SAP_ORDER_NR.Value? I'm not sure how this field is being serialized by I can recall some instances in .NET (value types I believe) where the actual data point is stored in a separate property (as opposed to being accessed on the field directly). If this is the case, you'd also have a related field (something like Response_1Run.SAP_ORDER_NR.IsNull) so that you can check for instances like the example above where the node is empty.

Comment: there is no .value, it says 'object'

Comment: Based on the screenshots above - it really looks like the serialization is kinda screwed up. Can you post the WSDL file that was used to create the web reference?

Comment: Hi Martin, you can download the wsdl on http://wtrns.fr/D614fXwg2DrFnZo (removed some urls and names for security)

Comment: Think I found a solution. updated the wsdl and added: " type="xsd:string" . Now I can access Response_1run.SAP_ORDER_NR.ToString without problem. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: @TomVD - That's exactly the solution! ...and exactly what I was going to check for in the WSDL document. As long as the WSDL/XML schema defines the correct type for the node - Visual Studio should serialize it into the object correctly so that you can access the type directly. Glad you were able to figure this out!! :)